# How to add header fields with swagger-codegen for an HTML documentation

Tags: html, swagger

I'm having troubles generating an HTML documentation with swagger-codegen. Calling `java -jar ./modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i swagger.yaml -l html -o docs.htm` generates an HTML file with all endpoints. However, the header fields for the endpoints are missing.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help and best regards,
Fabian

Comment: I think that's not supported in the templates but trivial to add.  Please open an issue:  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Comment: Thanks! I will report it.

Comment: As I just noticed, this was already reported: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/492